# Parameter Url Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to build a filter component with Vue , example i have 2 input form 1. Min Price and 2 Max Price and I want the query text that the user enters in an input field to be reactive with the query parameter in the URL
example i input min price : 1000

```
localhost/minprice=1000
```

when i input maxprice : 2000 the url be like :

```
localhost/minprice=1000&maxprice=2000
```

how to add multiple query parameter in the address without change the last parameter url i have ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a submit button, and then create a `URL` with query parameters using bound data, finally set the location object.

```
// in click handler
const url = `localhost://thePage?minprice=${this.minPrice}&maxprice=${this.maxprice}`
```

IMO it might be better to use the `hash` part of the URL, instead of query param, so the page does not need to reload.

```
const url = `localhost://thePage#minprice=${this.minPrice}&maxprice=${this.maxprice}`
```

You would filter in your component (without refreshing), and also set the hash.  Then if the user refreshed or bookmarked, the filter would be persisted. 
`window.location.hash = ...`

Either way, you would read the URL properties when loading your component and set the bound properties to them.

Comment: if i want to make automatic without submitting button how to make it ?

Comment: so if i input the value it will automatic change the url address bar , thank before

Comment: Add watchers to your bound data members.